# HTTP Post/Upload From Visual Basic 6

Tags: file-upload, vb6, http-post

I'm using Visual Basic 6 and want to do an HTTP POST to a server (it runs Java code) by sending a custom input field along with a PDF file. the PDF file would have to be base 64 bit encoded or use the normal way that HTTP POST work over the Internet when uploading a file.  Basically, I just want to upload a file from my Visual Basic 6 program.

How do I do this? Any example source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know how to load the PDF in to a byte array you've got to get it Base64 encoded and then post that to server using MIME multipart encoding.

You can utilise the MSXML libraries ability to perform Base64 encoding. See this [link](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp) for details.

Once you have the PDF as a Bas64 string you need to package that as MIME multipart.  You can use XMLHTTP object from MSXML to perform that posting for you:-

```
sEntityBody = "----boundary" & vbCrLf
sEntityBody = sEntityBody & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=fileInputElementName; filename=""" + sFileName + """" & vbCrLf
sEntityBody = sEntityBody & "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" & vbCrLf
sEntityBody = sEntityBody & "Content-Type: application/pdf" &  vbCrLf & vbCrLf
sEntityBody = sEntityBody & sPDFBase64 & vbCrLf
sEntityBody = sEntityBody & "-----boundary--" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----boundary")
xhr.Open "POST", sUrl, False
xhr.send sEntityBody
```

Perhaps not elegant or efficient but it should it work.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an unexpected error message when using your code above :-(

Comment: Its working now but the send() command is nagging when I send the sEntityBody to it. it gives me an error that the parameter is incorrect.

Comment: @Lennie: The last comment is unclear its working now?  What did you have to change?

Comment: 1. You cannot use `Content-Transfer-Encoding` with http (http://freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1945/83.htm). 2. `send` method does not like VT_BYREF params, use `xhr.send CVar(sBody)` as a workaround.

Comment: @wqw: Both good points although I've not had any trouble with sending Base64 like this but I can see how it is not strictly compliant with the specs.

Comment: Please correct the spelling of "Content-Disposition". I've just spent hours trying to find what's wrong with this request...

Comment: How can I add this Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP30 to my project?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to handle base 64

```
Private Declare Function CryptBinaryToString Lib "Crypt32.dll" Alias "CryptBinaryToStringW" (ByRef pbBinary As Byte, ByVal cbBinary As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pszString As Long, ByRef pcchString As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CryptStringToBinary Lib "Crypt32.dll" Alias "CryptStringToBinaryW" (ByVal pszString As Long, ByVal cchString As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pbBinary As Long, ByRef pcbBinary As Long, ByRef pdwSkip As Long, ByRef pdwFlags As Long) As Long

Public Function Base64Decode(sBase64Buf As String) As String
    Const CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 As Long = 1
    Dim bTmp() As Byte, lLen As Long, dwActualUsed As Long
    If CryptStringToBinary(StrPtr(sBase64Buf), Len(sBase64Buf), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, StrPtr(vbNullString), lLen, 0&, dwActualUsed) = 0 Then Exit Function       'Get output buffer length
    ReDim bTmp(lLen - 1)
    If CryptStringToBinary(StrPtr(sBase64Buf), Len(sBase64Buf), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, VarPtr(bTmp(0)), lLen, 0&, dwActualUsed) = 0 Then Exit Function 'Convert Base64 to binary.
    Base64Decode = StrConv(bTmp, vbUnicode)
End Function

Public Function Base64Encode(Text As String) As String
    Const CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 As Long = 1
    Dim lLen As Long, m_bData() As Byte, sBase64Buf As String
    m_bData = StrConv(Text, vbFromUnicode)
    If CryptBinaryToString(m_bData(0), UBound(m_bData) + 1, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, StrPtr(vbNullString), lLen) = 0 Then Exit Function  'Determine Base64 output String length required.
    sBase64Buf = String$(lLen - 1, Chr$(0)) 'Convert binary to Base64.
    If CryptBinaryToString(m_bData(0), UBound(m_bData) + 1, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, StrPtr(sBase64Buf), lLen) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Base64Encode = sBase64Buf
End Function
```