# Upload file to Internet Explorer using VBA

Tags: vba

I have an Internet Explorer window with an "add attachment" link. When pressing it a child window opens and there is a field with a "browse" button.

The issue is that it won't let you add the path manually, you must press "browse". I found the element but I can't change it's value cause it's read only and I can't get the browse window to open by code. How can I solve this?

```
<td  style="padding-bottom:1;padding-right:4;" rowspan=1 colspan = 1 Class = "cellpad" nowrap> 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="bUploadLocation_txtsFilename" VALUE="//ysi\ycrm/CRM_FILES/"> 
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="HDN_MANDATORYATTACHMENT_txtsFilename" VALUE=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="hdnUploadLimit_txtsFilename" value="70" > 
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="txtsFilename" CLASS ="INP" ONCHANGE = "javascript:`{fnSetChangeFlag('bUpdate1',1);}" TABINDEX = "3">`
<SCRIPT> NonMandatoryCheckArray1[NonMandatoryCheckArray1.length] ='txtsFilename' </SCRIPT> </td>
```

The attachment textbox and button are in the same line :

```
<INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="txtsFilename" CLASS ="INP" ONCHANGE = "javascript:{fnSetChangeFlag('bUpdate1',1);}" TABINDEX = "3">
```

How can I make the browse window to open, or even better, to change the value attribute to editable?

Comment: I'm going to assume you're automating IE from VBA. The short answer is you can't, it's a security feature so it's by design. The longer answer is that there is probably a much better way to do what you need.

Comment: Then what should I do? how can I upload my file? If I press the browse button it opens the browse window, but I can't press it form code

Comment: Normally you would POST the file directly to the server, but there's nowhere near enough information to help you here I'm afraid. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968998/http-post-upload-from-visual-basic-6