# Convert CURL command to VB6 (VBS)

Tags: curl, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

I have this curl command:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Token: 123" -F argument=value -F path=@C:/Users/Admin/file.txt https://example.com/api/file/`

And I'm trying to write it in VB6

```
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "POST", "https://example.com/api/file/", False
http.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
http.SetRequestHeader "Token", "123"
http.Send "argument=value&path="

MsgBox http.ResponseText
```

But I don't know how to send a file in POST-request. Could you help me?

Comment: See if the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968998/http-post-upload-from-visual-basic-6) helps.

Comment: Which is it, VB6 or VBscript? Those are different languages.

Comment: While it would be indeed a good idea to specify _exactly_ what language he's after, in the case of using the MSXML COM object to POST data, the code is pretty much interchangeable. Therefore @justin-ezequiel posted a good example.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Not sure I agree, it's only "interchangeable" if you understand the nuances of using [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/30593abb(v=vs.84)), VB and [VBS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/801s9ax8(v=vs.84)) syntaxes and how they differ.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Case in point, the linked accepted answer uses early binding to reference MSXML2 HTTP object which is not possible via VBScript as only late binding via COM through the `CreateObject()` method/function is available.

Comment: Yes. That's why I wrote _"pretty much"_, not _"100%"_. The OP already figured out to use MSXML for thje job and how to create the COM object in VBScript with `CreateObject()`. He's stuck at how to transmit a file and that's what the linked answer shows.